# CSS specificity query from Adam Freeman's book

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I'm reading Adam Freeman's "The Definitive Guide to HTML5", and have a question about CSS specificity. He gives the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            color: black;
        }

        a.myclass {
            color: white;
            background: grey;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <a href="http://apress.com">Visit the Apress website</a>
    <p>I like <span>apples</span> and oranges.</p>
    <a class="myclass" href="http://w3c.org">Visit the W3C website</a>
</body>

</html>
```

and states:

> In this case, the selector a.myclass includes a class attribute, which
>   means that the specificity of the style is 0-1-0 (0 id values + 1
>   other attributes + 0 element names). The other style has a specificity
>   of 0-0-0 (that is, it contains no id values, other attributes or
>   element names).

I would have expected that the "a.myclass" selector would have a specificity score of 0-1-1, because it includes *both* a class and an element. Similarly, I expected the "a" selector to have a score of 0-0-1. Entering these two selectors into this [CSS Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) does indeed produce the results I would expect. (except that this calculator includes inline styles in the score)

Can anyone explain Adam's comments, or should I report this as errata?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it if you actually understand how specificity works in CSS. Once you actually start writing CSS, you'll realize that you will probably never be calculating the specificity with these numbers.

Comment: i totaly agree with @AR7

Comment: Can we see your practical approach?

Comment: This book is almost four years old. Might be better to look elsewhere.

Comment: torazaburo: Yes I know it's old, but Adam is an excellent writer IMHO - I'll supplement the book with more up to date sources as well.

Comment: @torazaburo: So is the Selectors level 3 recommendation, oddly enough. (I realize we're talking about an HTML5 book here, but I couldn't help but notice this coincidence.)

Comment: @Andrew Orlov: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `a.myclass` selector has a specificity score of `0-1-1`. `a` is a type selector and has to be counted with a score of 1.

Please check w3.org specificity examples:

> ```
> *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> #x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> #s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
> ```

Reference: [w3.org - Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

Comment: Thankyou emmanuel. EDIT: Sorry for saying "thankyou" - I've just learnt the right way to accept an answer. :)